# How to 'print' my function on Visual Studio Code on the terminal?

Tags: node.js, terminal

As part of an exercise in Visual Code studio, I created a simple greeting function.

I wrote on the terminal node app.js with the expectation that will print the greeting+name. But unfortunately it doesn't print and I cannot find the solution to my problem.

```
function sayHello(name) {
    console.log('Hello' + name);

}
console.log('Chris')
```

I get this on the terminal

```
Christinas-iMac:first-app christinameliniotou$ node app.js
Christinas-iMac:first-app christinameliniotou$
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this program in vs code terminal as node app.js,

```js
function myHello(name) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

myHello('prince');
```

Comment: I did but I think the problem is not the code itself. I think is something wrong with the terminal but I can't figure out what it is. Maybe I have to insert something from the command palette?